# My own namespace could not be found?

Tags: silverlight, namespaces

I am trying to put a view in my main silverlight webpage by importing the namespace.

```
xmlns:Award="clr-namespace:OndernemersAward.Views"
```

Now I add the following to my website but it tells me it could not be found, but it is here, even the auto completion tells me that it's an option! See [screenshot](http://cl.ly/3D3x34022y3L1c0M0209/Image%202011-11-08%20at%208.08.13%20PM.png).

```
<Award:AdminLogin x:Name="Test"></Award:AdminLogin>
```

This is the XAML code for the AdminLogin page:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OndernemersAward.Views.AdminLogin"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Opacity="0.765" Fill="#FF8A8A8A"/>
        <Border CornerRadius="30" Background="#FF5C7590" Width="600" Height="250">
            <Button Content="Close" Width="100" Height="50" Name="btnClose"
                         Click="btnClose_Click" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

I really have no idea what is causing this and it's driving me loopy! :P

I hope somebody can help me, thanks.
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your project.  XAML cannot see classes/namespaces until you build  them

Comment: OMG, seriously?! Thank you so much... :P